# Is there database/SQL query syntax/function that could be used to compare amount of set bits

Tags: sql, database, nosql

Hi i'm looking for SQL query function or database framework that could be used to compare amount of "set bits" within integer/bigint, the order of the bits doesn't matter (similar with POPCNT instruction in SSE4)

for comparing each bit i could use masking operation but within SQL query comparing each bit doesn't provide the necessary flexibility in-case there are tolerated amount of "set bits", lets say you need to compare minimum 8 "set bits" (while the number of possible bits is larger than 8, lets say 64 bits) for your statement to be true, i don't think that would be possible with SQL query, even if it could i don't know how much it will affect performance and also i didn't want to read the query

so here's is my pseudocode about the query :

SELECT id FROM my_table WHERE popcnt(attrib & 0x1FFF) > 8

a. i use popcnt function as reminder on SSE4's popcnt instruction

b. attrib is an integer field, it can be integer, bigint, etc

i'm looking for standardized/specialized function (what database?) that could replace popcnt function on my pseudocode, or is there another mechanism on how to approach the similar result?

Comment: Bit operation are very database dependent.  Please add a database tag for the database you are using.

Comment: i'm looking for which database that support this operation, no particular database in mind